# Databinding a function in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular I found out you can bind a template to a function which returns an array, like this:

```
<div class="cal_row" id ="id_{{task.id}}" ng-repeat="task in calendar.filtered()">
  <div class="id">{{task.id}}</div>
      <div class="task">{{task.task}}</div>
  <div class="start">{{task.start}}</div>
  <div class="finish">{{task.finish}}</div>
</div>
```

It's pretty cool, because that way I can, for example, avoid having to keep a variable around just to maintain the filtered version of the data.

However, I also loose the binding with the original data: when the underlying data changes, I can't seem to get angular.js to spot the change, and update the view.

Is there  a way to do that? I tried to find anything in the docs, but couldn't

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make a change to some data from outside angular, you have to use `$myScope.$apply` so angular knows something has changed. [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)